# How is the recursive call actually working in merge sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort

```
void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r) { 
    if (l < r) { 
        int m = l + (r - l) / 2; 

        mergeSort(arr, l, m); 
        mergeSort(arr, m + 1, r); 

        merge(arr, l, m, r); 
    } 
}
```

I get how `mergesort` function breaks down the array into individual elements but isn't the `merge` function called only once?

Comment: I meant, we have divided the array, but shouldn't the merge() be recursive too? Starting with the first two broken elements, and then move on to the length of the array?

Comment: No `merge` is called once **per pair of recursive call to `mergeSort`**.

Comment: @hardikShettigar: if it helps: `merge` is being called as the last step coming back out of the recursion, so at that point the two parts being merged are each fully sorted (by the recursive calls).

Answer (score 0):

Edit: `merge` function does not just concatenate both arrays. It scan the arrays and adding to new array one by one.
Example: `[2, 4, 5, 6]` and `[1, 3, 7, 8]`. First compare 2 and 1. 1 is smaller, so we put in the merged array as the first element. Then compare 2 and 3, 2 is smaller so he is the next element in the merged array. Now compare 3 and 4 and etc.
You can implement `merge` with loops or with recursion. Does not really matter...

You did not show any implementation of `merge` function, it's outside of the code you published.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/ I am referring to the above website for the code. Let's say the start array was [8,1,4,9]              mergesort() will divide the array into individual elements, got it. So, after the splitting, merge() is called only once or after every recursive call of mergesort()?

Comment: @hardikShettigar after every recursive call. It is part of the function, so every time function executes it calls to merge. You should think about recursion in the following way: let's assume someone magically can sort two subarray, what will I do then? just merge them. How will you get this magic done? call to yourself. Take care only for "1 iteration" and recursion will do the rest